# Trying to sort fetch results by keys taken from the results

Tags: php

How do I create an array of SQL fetched results and sort by keys that are taken from the results themselves?

For example, here is how the results from the database look like:

```
$results = array(
    [0] => array(
        'id' => 'cat',
        'name' => 'Kitty'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'id' => 'dog',
        'name' => 'Rex'
    )
);
```

I want to turn into:

```
$results = array(
    ['cat'] => array(
        'id' => 'cat',
        'name' => 'Kitty'
    ),
    ['dog'] => array(
        'id' => 'dog',
        'name' => 'Rex'
    )
);
```

I can do it with a `foreach` loop, but is there a built-in function that I'm missing?

Comment: Without seeing your code this is too broad question. If you use PDO (which you probably should) you can do that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the function [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php) does exactly what you want.

```
$results = array(
 array('id' => 'cat', 'name' => 'Kitty'),
 array('id' => 'dog', 'name' => 'Rex')
);

$res = array_column($results,null,'id');

echo "<pre>";
var_export($res);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'cat' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'cat',
    'name' => 'Kitty',
  ),
  'dog' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'dog',
    'name' => 'Rex',
  ),
)
```